# Сделать из массива водопад чисел по условию

Tags: php, javascript, математика

Есть массив вида `array(100,90,70,60,50,40,30) = 440` (сумма чисел);
Нужно сделать из него водопад примерно такого вида `array(77,75,72,67,62,47,40) = 440` (сумма чисел);

Необходимо чтобы в нем не было значений больше > 80(к примеру) при этом он должен быть преобразован в виде водопада, а все значения которые больше раскиданы на все элементы по убыванию.

То есть, первые два элемента:

```
100-80=20;
90-80=10;
```

Всего 20+10=30 - это числа которые нужно раскидать

Плюс начало водопада у нас в условии первые два числа, которые больше 80, но в результате они должны быть меньше:

```
80-77(к примеру)=3
80-75(к примеру)=5
```

Итого числа, которые нужно раскидать 30+3+5=38;

В результате должно выйти примерно так:

```
array(77,75,72,67,62,47,40) = 440
```

Сам я в математики не силен, так что вся надежда на Вас :) Напишите плиз мат. алгоритм. Спасибо!

Update про число 80

Вместо числа 80 может быть число любого значения, но не больше чем первый элемент массива. И от этого числа должен идти вниз наш водопад.

Update
Парни я вроде сделал водопадик. Вот в коде https://jsfiddle.net/un04ukm7/10/ примерно то что я хотел. Все ночь спал и решал, спал и решал )) Всем спасибо.

Comment: Тогда это лучше убрать,а то на мысли наводит плохие - `Решение можно написать как на php, так и на javascript`

Comment: Хорошо, убрал :)

Comment: @Maksym толку-то? Вопрос все равно не содержит внятного описания почему ответ верный. Слова "больше > 80(к примеру)" дают намек на то, что кроме входного числа 440 есть дополнительные параметры и так далее.

Comment: Какое Вам еще описание надо чтобы вы успокоились. Что из условия Вам конкретно не понятно?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Если честно я тут читаю и не могу понять вообще ничего - просто зацепился. 12 часов ночи говорят за себя))Утром проснусь и подумаю))

Comment: водопад, как я понимаю, это когда следующий шаг больше или равен предыдущему? а кол-во элементов в массиве должно сохраниться?

Comment: Если до `Итого числа, которые нужно раскидать 30+3+5=38;` еще хоть как то понятно, то после ничего... По какому принципу раскидываем? Почему к 30 добавили (10) к 40 (7) а к 50 (12). Каковы правила   `раскидать`? Или результата?

Comment: Ну и главный вопрос какую задачу данный алгоритм решает? Может вам он и не нужен? А так, как задан вопрос сейчас, задание для студента который его и не понял. Инфа 146%!!!1111

Comment: Да, количество элементов должно сохраниться. Водопад, это когда следующий шаг меньше предыдущего. Насчет того, по какому принципу раскидываем. У нас есть n элементов, в данном случае 38, которые мы должны равномерно раскидать по всему массиву, сохранив при этом саму его структуру, чтобы  числа были по убыванию. Может вам он и не нужен? Нужен, вот поэтому и спрашиваю, и сам пытаюсь решить. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не особо сложная, но с "изюминкой".
Если считать, что вся последовательность состоит из одинаковых элементов (80), то при заданной сумме (440) образуется избыток `$excess = 120`.
В первом приближении этот избыток можно скомпенсировать, задавая последовательность как убывающую арифметическую прогрессию с известным первым членом `$first = 80` и разностью `-$d`. Величина `$d` вычисляется по формуле `$d = [$excess/$inc_sum]`, где `$inc_sum` - сумма арифметической прогресии длины `$cnt = 7` с нулевым первым членом и разностью 1.
Оставшуюся часть превышения `$ex` можно скомпенсировать, дополнительно декрементируя очередной элемент. При этом следует иметь в виду, что уменьшение элемента с номером `$i` на единицу изменяет сумму на величину `$cnt-i`.

Программа на PHP имеет вид:

```
$issue = [100, 90, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30];
$first = 80;
$sum = array_sum($issue);
$cnt = count($issue);
$excess = $first*$cnt -$sum;
print "Исходный массив:";
var_dump($issue);
print "Сумма элементов: $sum, Максимальный элемент: $first Количество элементов: $cnt";
if($excess < 0){
    print "нет решения";
}else{
    $inc_sum = $cnt*($cnt-1)/2;
    $d = (int)floor($excess/$inc_sum);
    $ex = $excess - $d*$inc_sum;
    print "<br> Избыток суммы: $excess Шаг водопада: $d Избыток суммы: $ex";
}
$result = [$first];
for($i = 1; $i < $cnt; $i++){
    $delta = $cnt - $i;
    if($delta <= $ex){
        $ex -= $delta++;
        $result[] = end($result) - $d - 1;  
    }else{
        $result[] = end($result) - $d;  
    }
}
printf("<br>Результат: ", array_sum($result));
var_dump($result);      
printf("Сумма элементов = %d", array_sum($result));
```

Результат:

```
Исходный массив:
array (size=7)
  0 => int 100
  1 => int 90
  2 => int 70
  3 => int 60
  4 => int 50
  5 => int 40
  6 => int 30
Сумма элементов: 440, Максимальный элемент: 80 Количество элементов: 7
Избыток суммы: 120 Шаг водопада: 5 Избыток суммы: 15
Результат:
array (size=7)
  0 => int 80
  1 => int 74
  2 => int 68
  3 => int 62
  4 => int 57
  5 => int 52
  6 => int 47
Сумма элементов = 440
```

Comment: Ну хоть один помощь предложил. А то до этого только тапками закидывали )) Спасибо, что не поленились решить.

Comment: Они позорят наш сайт :)